# Xcode 15.2 build error: Opaque pointers are only supported in -opaque-pointers mode

Tags: ios, xcode

error: Opaque pointers are only supported in -opaque-pointers mode (Producer: 'APPLE_1_1500.1.0.2.5_0' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1500.1.0.2.5_0')
LLVM ERROR: Can't load module, abort.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Abort trap: 6
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

Try add Other Linker Flags  -ld64 but no luck

Answer (score 0):

LLVM 15: Opaque pointers are only supported in -opaque-pointers mode #3666
https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3666

According to this article, add **-Wl,-mllvm,--opaque-pointers** to Other Linker Flags can bypass this error.

[Xcode Build Settings Other Linker Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPYtH.jpg)